# The requested URL xxx was not found on this server

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, localhost

I have been tearing my hair on this for hours..please help..

I have been running several websites on localhost for months without a hitch. Unfortunately last week I had do do a fresh instal of Windows due to a disk corruption. I now find that i get the dreaded "The requested URL /stellar/about-us/ was not found on this server" when I try to access any of the menu links. The Homepage works fine.. its menu links that do not work.

I have changed the httpd.conf as follows:
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

.htaccess is also fine too. Reproduced below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stellar/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./stellar/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What have I missed? Please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

The htaccess file that you have must be in the `/stellar/` folder. Assuming that it is, you have an error in the last rule:

```
RewriteRule ./stellar/index.php [L]
```

You're missing a space between the `.` and the `/`:

```
RewriteRule . /stellar/index.php [L]
```

And because of the rewrite base, you don't need the `/stellar/` part at all:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks.. I saw that too and fixed it...even though I did not think it made a difference. Obviously, it did.

Answer (score 1):

@user3234280 Everything is fine, If you have exactly what i have you should have no problems at all!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /wp_home/
 RewriteRule ^Pattern /wp_home/Substitution [QSA,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /wp_home/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

where /wp_home/ is WordPress' home directory (or the root URL / if WordPress is installed in your web root.)

If you need anymore help check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

make sure you have this also included somewhere in your html or php

```
<?php
    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = array( 'Pattern' => 'Substitution' );
    print_r($wp_rewrite->mod_rewrite_rules());
?>
```

Comment: The only line that I do not have is: RewriteRule ^Pattern /wp_home/Substitution [QSA,L]

Comment: You might or might not need this for this to work, but if you havnt already add this to your html or php look in the edited text i just posted

Comment: Thanks. I have now fixed it. All I had to do was to re-save the Permalinks in Wordpress Admin portal even though I had not touched it. Thanks for the link to the reference.

Comment: No problem, and Your Welcome! :)